# Display weekly/monthly/yearly high/low on any timeframe

Tags: pine-script

I would like to display the weekly/monthly/yearly highs and lows for the current and previous week/month/year on any timeframe. As an example, if I'm on the 4h chart, I would like to see an indication of the the current week's high/low as well as an indication of the previous week's high/low. The same for the current and previous month/year. The indications should only occur at the bar on which the high/low was formed.

I wrote something like this (only for the weekly high/low; the others would be implemented similarly), but it shows indications on *every bar* (for the 4h chart for example):

```
//@version=5

indicator(title="test", shorttitle="test", overlay=true)

highs = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "W", high)
lows = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "W", low)
plotchar(ta.valuewhen(high == highs[0], high, 1), "current_high", "▼", location.abovebar, size = size.tiny, color = color.lime)
plotchar(ta.valuewhen(low == lows[0], low, 1), "current_low", "▲", location.belowbar, size = size.tiny, color = color.blue)
plotchar(ta.valuewhen(high == high[1], high, 1), "previous_high", "▼", location.abovebar, size = size.tiny, color = color.teal)
plotchar(ta.valuewhen(low == lows[1], low, 1), "previous_low", "▲", location.belowbar, size = size.tiny, color = color.maroon)
```

Bonus question: how do I indicate the highs/lows using style_label_down/style_label_up because labels require x,y coordinates as input?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if it's a new week using `ta.change()` function, and then use `label` to show the results you wish for only when a new week begins or if it's the last bar. For example:

```
//@version=5

indicator(title="test", shorttitle="test", overlay=true)

isNewWeek = ta.change(time("W"))

highs = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "W", high)
lows = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "W", low)

if isNewWeek or barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, high, 
     text="Current High " + str.tostring(highs) + 
     "\nCurrent Low " + str.tostring(lows) + 
     "\nPrevios High " + str.tostring(highs[1]) +
     "\nPrevious Low " + str.tostring(lows[1]), 
     style=label.style_label_down)
```

** Notice the line breaks if you are copy-pasting the code.

[image]

Comment: Very clever! Thanks for the solution. I can't figure out whether it's possible to print the label on the bar where the high/low happens. Would this be possible?